# Angular forEach not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have problem with read data in angularJS.

This example with fixed obj work fine:

```
var obj = { "done": "1"};
  angular.forEach(st, function (value, key) {
  alert(key + ': ' + value);
  var returnVal = value; //Get number 1 that is OK
});
```

My example:

[image: http://prntscr.com/9vegm8]

My function data return string `({ "done": "1"});`  after replace `var obj2 = data.repl`ace("(", "").replace(")", "");`get format like it is obj in above example. obj = { "done": "1"};  obj2 = { "done": "1"};`

When put obj2 in `angular.forEach` not working.

I'm  trying to use stringify,`angular.fromJson` but nothing!

Any solution?

Comment: Why the api returns an invalid JSON string ({ "done": "1"}); ? It suppose to be just { "done": "1"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, obj2 was a JSON string and you need to parse it into object before sending it to forEach.

Here is the working example.

```js
var data = '({ "done": "1"});';

var obj2 = data.replace(/[();]/g, '');

angular.forEach(JSON.parse(obj2), function (value, key) {
  alert(key + ': ' + value);
  var returnVal = value; //Get number 1 that is OK
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What you are getting in alert 2?

Comment: Looks like i have missed to replace the semicolon. Use this to replace the data. var obj2 = data.replace(/[();]/g, '');

I also updated my answer.

Comment: Tnx a lot of...what is it (/[();]/g, ''); any example?

Comment: I replaced the characters "();" using regular expression. data.replace(/[();]/g, '') is equal to data.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace(';', '')